# Windows authentication with IdentityServer

Tags: openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have a Web API application, an Identity Server application and a desktop client. My goal is to have the desktop client use **windows authentication** through Identity Server to authenticate the desktop client to the Web API. This works fine without windows authentication: the desktop client presents a browser window for the client to enter credentials. Then the credentials are validated and the user is granted access to the desktop application.

I set things up like this for Windows Authentication:
IdentityServer app runs on its own app pool. Has only Windows Authentication enabled
Web API app runs on its own app pool. Has anonymous authentication enabled.

But the problem is that when the Desktop client tries to connect to get the openid configuration it fails saying: "Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'http://{server}/IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration'". If I enable Anonymous Authentication on IdentityServer the error will go away but then of course all calls will be anonymous and the user will not be authenticated.
Moreso, if after the call is made I disable the anonymous access once again (because the openId call already happened) the user will be authenticated and I will get the expected behavior.

*So my question is: how to I instruct the server to allow the call to Unable to create to obtain configuration from: 'IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration' to work anonymously while the others will work only authenticated?*

Comment: Well as you have pointed out, some endpoints must remain `[AllowAnonymous]`. I thought this worked out of the box nowadays, but you haven't provided how you enabled config. In IIS, you can control config settings by path as well. `<location path="api/controller1"><system.web><authorization><deny users="?" />...`

Comment: Yes, but IdentityServer/.well-known/openid-configuration is not an api I control. It's from the IdentityServer library

Comment: it's still a path under your web application that can be controller on a more granular level in web.config

Comment: .well-known/openid-configuration is handled internally by IdentityServer4 library. And I tried setting that location with anonymous auth but it doesn't seem to work. Do you know how I could specify that particular route doesn't require authentication?

Comment: if you hit that route manually in the browser, does it prompt for windows auth?

Comment: Yes, it does actually

Comment: Hence my point, it has nothing to do with the fact that it is an internally registered route. You applied this authentication on top, therefore you can remove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194766/discussion-between-cristi71000-and-vidmantas-blazevicius).